# What does lambda x=x mean?

Tags: python, lambda, range

I am new to python and I am trying to understand the logic here:

What does lambda **x=x** mean? in the complete function below:

```
tables = [lambda x=x: x*10 for x in range(1, 11)]
for table in tables:
    print(table())
```

Comment: That syntax doesn't look valid to me. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 6):

There are two different variables named `x` here.

The first one is the parameter, which is a local variable *in* the function being defined.

The second is a variable visible *in the scope* where the function is being defined. Its value is stored as the default value to use for the first variable `x` if no argument is passed when the function is called.

It is far less confusing if you just use two different names for the two different variables:

```
tables = [lambda x=y: x*10 for y in range(1, 11)]
```

This is the short way of writing

```
tables = []
tables.append(lambda x=1: x*10)
tables.append(lambda x=2: x*10)
# etc.
```

---

Based on how each function is called in the following loop, the intention appears to be to never actually pass an argument when the function is called, and that what we really want is to automate something like

```
tables = []
tables.append(lambda : 1 * 10)
tables.append(lambda : 2 * 10)
# etc.
```

The naive approach

```
tables = [lambda: x*10 for x in range(1, 11)]
```

fails because `x` is a free variable in the body of the function; it does *not* get replaced with the value of `x` at the time the function is called. Doing this, you end up with a list of 10 identical function, all of which depend on the last value assigned to `x` before the function is called.

By binding a default value that is evaluated *immediately* to the parameter, you "inject" the current value of `x` into the function right away, so that you end up with a list of 10 different functions.

Answer (score 0):

tables = [lambda y = x: x*10 for x in range(1, 11)]
for table in tables:
print(table())
The output is 10 100s printed one below the other
I an unable to understand the logic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).